# Delphi TRichEdit Set background shape as rounded edge rectangle

Tags: delphi, shaped-window, trichedit

My problem is to set the background shape to something like rounded edge rectangle. The fact that when you put background color on the text on TRichedit, the background shape would be a rectangle, not rounded edge. I would like to put some sample image but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

What it sounds like your trying to do I do not believe the current implementation of TRichEdit is capable of...that control is a wrapper over the windows rich edit control, and you can only do what was programmed into that control, or allowed for.

Another option would be to use one of the Delphi rich edit alternatives such as [TRichView](http://trichview.com/) or [WPTools](http://www.wpcubed.com/products/wptools/index.htm), both of which are complete rich editors with source code that you CAN enhance to meet your request.  I have actually used both in various projects over time as a more powerful replacement for TRichEdit, and would recommend either.